# I would like to know the meaning of this sentence;

Tags: meaning

Sentence is this:   For fifty years this approach has not been quite *'as blissful as ignorance'*

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignorance_is_bliss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However...

In [context](https://www.nytimes.com/books/first/g/greene-universe.html), with the rest of the sentence:

> *In all but the most extreme situations, physicists study things that are either small and light (like atoms and their constituents) or things that are huge and heavy (like stars and galaxies), but not both. This means that they need use only quantum mechanics or only general relativity and can, with a furtive glance, shrug off the barking admonition of the other. For fifty years this approach has not been quite as blissful as ignorance, but it has been pretty close.*

He is saying the problem has not been much of a problem at all, almost as "blissful" as not even knowing you have a problem.

Comment: To Neil, 
       The phrase in question is found in this very paragraph.  I shall be grateful to you for the elaboration.  Your illustration made me grasp the exact idea of the phrase without any ambiguity.  So once again I shall thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It means simply that the approach was bad.

It referes to common phrase `Ignorance is bliss`, which means "the less you know, the happier you are".

Comment: To Bartosz,
Your definition to that phrase matches perfectly.   I shall be so grateful to you for providing me an answer.   Thank you very much!